# Flink hive api query exception: Distinct without an aggregation

Tags: hive, apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-batch

I have the following exception when querying Hive with Flink's Hive table API connector: `Distinct without an aggregation`.

However, the sql query is executed correctly when using Hue interface to query hive.
I'm wondering if this problem due to a bad compatibility with flink?

**Flink version**: `1.14.2`

**Hive version**: `2.1.1`

**SQL statement**:

```sql
select devid as pdevid,
    count(distinct vtype) as vip_type_trans
from events
where dt = '20220702'
    and utype > -1
group by devid
having count(distinct vtype) > 1
```

**Exception**:

```java
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Distinct without an aggregation.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Distinct without an aggregation.
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.logicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:304)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:272)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParser.analyzeSql(HiveParser.java:290)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParser.processCmd(HiveParser.java:238)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParser.parse(HiveParser.java:208)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.sqlQuery(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:716)
        at com.zhhainiao.wp.stat.PaidConversationRate$.main(PaidConversationRate.scala:158)
        at com.zhhainiao.wp.stat.PaidConversationRate.main(PaidConversationRate.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Distinct without an aggregation.
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genSelectLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:2275)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:2749)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:2647)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:2688)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:2647)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.genLogicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:2688)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserCalcitePlanner.logicalPlan(HiveParserCalcitePlanner.java:284)
```

Answer (score 0):

> That is, flink is not fully compatible with hive sql syntax？

Flink is not fully compatible with the Hive SQL Syntax. There is one open Flink ticket regarding Hive while using DISTINCT, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19004. If that matches with your current problem, you can track that item. Else I would recommend that you open a new Flink Jira ticket for this bug.